# How to use JSON file from HTML input in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

In my current Angular 8 project I have two JSON files which should be connected to one JSON array. The new file should then be exported.

After googling for a long time I didn't find a solution how to use the two JSON files, which I call up via two HTML inputs, so that I can combine both files in the Angular Component to form a JSON array with input from both JSON files.

My current code:

**JsonConverterComponent.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="Json1">Json 1</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="json1" type="file" id="Json1" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="Json2">Json 2</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="json2" type="file" id="Json2" required>
</div>
<button [buttonLabel]="buttonNameJson" [disableCheck]="!json1 || !json2" (click)="combineJSON()"></button>
```

**JsonConverterComponent.TS**

```
export class JsonConverterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  buttonNameJson = "Combine JSON";
  json1: File;
  json2: File;
  test: File;

  one = this.json1;
  two = this.json2;

  public combineJSON() {
    this.test = this.one;
    console.log(this.test);
  }
}
```

If I just want to call up the content of one of the two imported JSON files, I always get the error "undefined".

What do I have to do so that I can use the individual JSON in JsonConverterComponent.ts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ngModel` directive can't be used on a `input` of type `file`, you have to react on the `change` event like this:

```
<input (change)="onFileChange($event)" type="file" id="Json1" required>

<input (change)="onFileChange($event)" type="file" id="Json2" required>
```

Then in the TypeScript file:

```
onFileChange(event){
    const fileToLoad = event.target.files[0];
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
        const textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        const json = JSON.parse(textFromFileLoaded);
        console.log(json);
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine so far, but when I try to connect the two JSON files I only get one fakepath. `C: \ fakepath \ JsonOne.jsonC: \ fakepath \ JsonTwo.json`

Comment: What do you mean by "connect the two JSON files?"

Comment: I want to convert the content of both JSON files into one file

Comment: `onload` event will be fired after the content is read so your logic to convert the two JSON files should be inside the `onLoad` function.

Comment: how extract the const json in some component property?

Comment: Just assign it to one class property, let's say `this.fileContent = json`. Note that you should replace the callback `function(fileLoadedEvent)` with an arrow function, then display it with with the JSON pipe: `{{ fileContent | json }}`